# create a custom controller back office on Custom module in prestashop

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

```
1) i want to create a custom controller on custom module in prestashop without tab.and get browser url Link.

2) how to create a controller url link with tocken on twig file.
```

*i have successfully created module and installed in my PS.*

**i create a controller [Checkstatus.php]**

**file path** `module/mymodule/contollers/admin/Checkstatus.php`

```
<?php

class CheckstatusController extends  ModuleAdminController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->page_name = 'checkstatus'; // page_name and body id
        echo "sfg";
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parenrt::init();
    }
    public function demoAction()
    {
        return $this->render('@Modules/your-module/templates/admin/demo.html.twig');
    }

}
```

**my Custom module**

```
<?php


if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
exit;
}

class MyModule extends  PaymentModule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'MyCustomModule';
        $this->tab = 'payments XYZ';
        $this->version                = '1.0';
        $this->author                 = 'XYZ Technologies';
        $this->bootstrap              = true;
        $this->displayName            = 'XYZ';
        $this->description            = 'XYZ.';
        $this->confirmUninstall       = 'Are you sure you want to uninstall XYZ module?';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->allow_countries        = array('CH', 'LI', 'AT', 'DE');
        $this->allow_currencies       = array('CHF', 'EUR');

        parent::__construct();

    }

    /**
    * Install this module and register the following Hooks:
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }

        Db::getInstance()->execute('
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'MyCustomModule` (
                `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `customer_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
                `MyCustomModule` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                `lastcheck_date` date,
                `add_date` date,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
        ');

        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('Statusbtnoncustomerview');
    }
    /**
     * Uninstall this module and remove it from all hooks
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall() && $this->uninstallDb() && $this->unregisterHook('Statusbtnoncustomerview');
    }

    public function uninstallDb()
    {
        return Db::getInstance()->execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '._DB_PREFIX_.'MyCustomModule');
    }

    public function hookStatusbtnoncustomerview()
    {
        /**
         * Verify if this module is enabled
         */
        if (!$this->active) {
            return;
        }
        return $this->fetch('module:MyCustomModule/views/templates/hook/personal_information.html.twig');
    }
    /**
     * Returns a string containing the HTML necessary to
     * generate a configuration screen on the admin
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        $output = null;
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submit'.$this->name)) {

            // get configuration fields value
            $MyCustomModule_Account_Data = strval(Tools::getValue('MyCustomModule_Account_Data'));
            $credit_Checkbox =  strval(Tools::getValue('credit_Checkbox_1'));
            $interval_Month = strval(Tools::getValue('Interval_Month'));

            if (
                !$MyCustomModule_Account_Data ||
                empty($MyCustomModule_Account_Data) ||
                !Validate::isGenericName($MyCustomModule_Account_Data)
            ) {
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Please Enter MyCustomModule Account Data.'));
            } else{

                // Update configuration fields value
                Configuration::updateValue('MyCustomModule_Account_Data', $MyCustomModule_Account_Data);
                Configuration::updateValue('credit_Checkbox_1', $credit_Checkbox);
                Configuration::updateValue('Interval_Month', $interval_Month);


                // Display message after successfully submit value
                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
            }
        }

        return $output.$this->displayForm();
    }
    /**
     * Display a form
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return form html using helper form
     */
    public function displayForm()
    {
        // Get default language
        $defaultLang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        $credit_Checkbox = [
            [
                'id'=>1,
                'name'=>'',
                'val' => 1
            ]
        ];
        // Init Fields form array
        $fieldsForm[0]['form'] = [
            'legend' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Configuration'),
            ],
            'input' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('MyCustomModule Account Data'),
                    'name' => 'MyCustomModule_Account_Data',
                    'required' => true
                ],
                [

                    'type'=>'checkbox',
                    'label'=> $this->l('credit'),
                    'name'=>'credit_Checkbox',
                    'values'=>[
                        'query'=>$credit_Checkbox,
                        'id'=>'id',
                        'name'=>'name'
                    ]

                ],
                [
                    'type' => 'html',
                    'html_content' => '<input type="number" min="0" step="1" value="'.Configuration::get('Interval_Month').'" name="Interval_Month">',
                    'label' => $this->l('interval Month'),
                    'name' => 'Interval_Month',
                    'size' => 20
                ],
            ],
            'submit' => [
                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
            ]
        ];


        $helper = new HelperForm();

        // Module, token and currentIndex
        $helper->module = $this;
        $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;

        // Language
        $helper->default_form_language = $defaultLang;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $defaultLang;

        // Title and toolbar
        $helper->title = $this->displayName;
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
        $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
        $helper->submit_action = 'submit'.$this->name;
        $helper->toolbar_btn = [
            'save' => [
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ],
            'back' => [
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
                'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
            ]
        ];

        // Load current value
        $helper->fields_value['MyCustomModule_Account_Data'] = Configuration::get('MyCustomModule_Account_Data');
        $helper->fields_value['credit_Checkbox_1'] = Configuration::get('credit_Checkbox_1');
        $helper->fields_value['Interval_Month'] = Configuration::get('Interval_Month');


        return $helper->generateForm($fieldsForm);
    }


}
```

**i trying this url :** http://localhost/prestashop/admin482vzxnel/index.php?module=mymodule&controller=checkstatus

**geting error :**

```
Page not found
The controller checkstatus is missing or invalid.
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to create a module not an override. From here you can generate a basic module to install in your PS https://validator.prestashop.com/generator. once installed in module code you can access an use all PS global constant, helpers and classes and controllers. here the official guide to module development https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/

Comment: i have already  created custom module and done it. wait i updated my question.

Comment: include Checkstatus.php in module main file, and create a method into the module controller where instanciate the checkstatus Class. The issue is that, for PS the main controller is your MyModule Class and you can't have two controller in a module, but you can use a Class Object into your module's main controller methods. Use PS native Hooks to execute your code where you need, you can generate your token in Module constructor or use the PS static_token. See the code from other module and take code example on how them pass Variables to TPL

Comment: sorry but i am not  understand i request to please updated my module and how to put checkstatus file .

Answer (score 0):

To include a Class in a module  you can use php require. Once included in module main file you can create an instance of you class where you want in your module.
To assign variable that you can use on template there is `$this->context->smarty->assig()` function.

The code Below is just an example of how include and use a Class in a custom module Controller.

Even the edit in the  `hookStatusbtnoncustomerview()`  is an example of how retrieve the module link and the link on his method, so take the code below such as it is, only an example

```
    require_once (dirname(__FILE__)).'contollers/admin/Checkstatus.php';

            class MyModule extends  PaymentModule
            {
                public function __construct()
                {
                    $this->name = 'MyCustomModule';
                    $this->tab = 'payments XYZ';
                    $this->version                = '1.0';
                    $this->author                 = 'XYZ Technologies';
                    $this->bootstrap              = true;
                    $this->displayName            = 'XYZ';
                    $this->description            = 'XYZ.';
                    $this->confirmUninstall       = 'Are you sure you want to uninstall XYZ module?';
                    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7.0', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
                    $this->allow_countries        = array('CH', 'LI', 'AT', 'DE');
                    $this->allow_currencies       = array('CHF', 'EUR');

                    $this->checkController = null;

                    parent::__construct();

                }

                 private function _useCheckstatus(){

                      $this->checkController = new CheckstatusController();


                }

                public function MyMethod (){

                   $this->_useCheckstatus();
                   $this->checkController->demoAction();

                }

        public function hookStatusbtnoncustomerview()
            {
                /**
                 * Verify if this module is enabled
                 */
                if (!$this->active) {
                    return;
                }

                $this->context->smarty->assign(
                         array(
                           'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MyCustomModule'),
                           'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('MyCustomModule', 'mymethod'),
                           'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
                    )
                   );

                return $this->fetch('module:MyCustomModule/views/templates/hook/personal_information.html.twig');
            }
        .........
```

it's not easy to investigate how prestashop works, so my tip is: look at the code from other modules, and take example from them.

Instead if you need to override a Core Prestashop Controller in your module you have to put the override file in /mymodule/override/controllers/admin/ModuleAdminController.php. installing/resetting the module will put this file within root/override/controllers/admin/ folder and the override becomes active. just remember to clear PS cache in "advanced settings->performance"